# Which file system was I using?

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, system-restore

This is an odd question of a somewhat forensic nature.
I was running a server, which originally had openSuse 11.4 installed, and was upgraded twice (to v12.3 and v13.1). Recently, an update messed up the machines boot sector and partition table, which I was unable to recover from - despite having a backup.

I have since reinstalled a different OS, but there's one thing that I'm missing:
The server has 3 large HDDs (2TB, 2TB, 1TB) which previously were mounted as *one* massive 5TB volume. Back when I configured all that, I used openSuse's YaST (GUI tool) to accomplish this.
Now I want to recreate that *combined* 5TB volume, so I can access my data on it. I don't have a backup of the initial 5TB volume setup/configuration, and I don't have a backup of the data either.

**How can I recreate this 5TB volume?** I.e. which FS was I using and how do I mount that volume?
I am looking for answers that tell me how to approach this puzzle.

I remember that setting all this up required that I use *only* equally sized partitions to tie together. So I created two 1TB partitions on each 2TB disk, and one 1TB partition on the 1TB drive. I don't know in which order I glued them together. I also remember that there was no redundancy involved, or anything else that I had to configure to store my data more reliable.

The three disk devices are `/dev/sdb` (2TB), `/dev/sdc` (2TB) and `/dev/sdc` (1TB).

```
# lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0  37.3G  0 disk
>>sda1                          8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
>>sda2                          8:2    0     1K  0 part
>>sda5                          8:5    0    37G  0 part
  >>server--vg-root (dm-1)    252:1    0  29.3G  0 lvm  /
  >>server--vg-swap_1 (dm-2)  252:2    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                             8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
>>fusedLV (dm-0)              252:0    0   4.6T  0 lvm
sdc                             8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
>>fusedLV (dm-0)              252:0    0   4.6T  0 lvm
sdd                             8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
>>fusedLV (dm-0)              252:0    0   4.6T  0 lvm
sr0                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

.

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/fusedLV: 5001.0 GB, 5000952545280 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 607997 cylinders, total 9767485440 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Comment: It sounds like you set up a RAID-0 array. Unless your data has no value this is a bad idea.

Comment: The data is not super-important. Back then I didn't seem to know what I was doing in the FS department.

Answer (score 1):

The default filesystem for OpenSUSE 11.4 was probably [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3). From your description you probably built that on top of a RAID-0 [md](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm) device. You can rebuild the RAID-0 device with a command like

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=stripe --raid-devices=5 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdb2
```

having suitably partitioned the drives.

Comment: sadly, `ls /dev/sd*` does not list any partitions on `sdb`, `sdc` or `sdd`

Comment: @derabbink create them then ????